# mysql database backup using mysqldump

Tags: java, mysql, runtime.exec, database-backups

I'm trying to take a backup of a mysql database using the following code.

```
    public boolean backupDB() {

    String executeCmd = "mysqldump -u root -p 1234 --add-drop-database -B test -r D:\\backup\\aaa.sql";
    Process runtimeProcess;
    try {
        runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
        if (processComplete == 0) {
            System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

But it always gives me this error:

```
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

How can I resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `PATH` external variable to contain a path to `mysqldump.exe` or use absolute path to the file.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%MYSQL_HOME%\bin
```

where `MYSQL_HOME` is a variable that contains a path to MySQL server installation folder.

When use with absolute path. Note, that this path depends on your comp and shouldn't be use in production code.

```
String executeCmd = "C:\\Programs Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\bin\\mysqldump.exe -u root -p 1234 --add-drop-database -B test -r D:\\backup\\aaa.sql";
```

Comment: should I download the mysqldump.exe from somewhere?

Comment: How to use absolute path to the file?

Comment: I tried set PATH=%PATH%;%MYSQL_HOME%\bin  but it doesn't work

Comment: Like this `"C:\\Programs Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\bin\\mysqldump.exe"`.

Comment: Where should I add this?

Comment: To Java file, but path might very on your comp.

Comment: According to my question, instead of D:\\backup\\aaa.sql ?

Comment: Is there anyway to get the mysql path programatically?

Comment: To get it programmatically, I would load up the Program files and program files (x86), scan both of these folders for a folder named "MySQL" (or something similar), then within that folder, search for a folder that contains "MySQL Server" (regex: "/MySQL Server \d+\.\d+"), locate "bin" within the "MySQL Server ..." folder, then check of bin contains "mysqldump.exe". That method is a little brute-force and there might be an easier/more efficient method, but that's just an idea.

Comment: I don't know may be you need to read an installation guide, you can find it on [mysql](http://mysql.org) site. Better to set a HOME env variable and update PATH, so you can run any command from mysql bin from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Before you use mysqldump please specify its path like this :

```
String executeCmd = "\""+mysqldump_path+"bin\\mysqldump.exe\" --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=root --password=pass database > \""+path+"\"";
 runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c",executeCmd});

       int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
       System.out.println(processComplete);

       if(processComplete == 0) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup Created Successfully !");
           System.out.println("Backup Created Successfully !");
       }
       else{
          System.out.println("Couldn't Create the backup !");
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Couldn't Create the backup !");
       }
```

if it Creates error and goes of abnormally then this a pic of code that u can add to see the errors :

```
InputStream errorStream = runtimeProcess.getErrorStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[errorStream.available()];
errorStream.read(buffer);
String str = new String(buffer);
System.out.println(str);
```